# PostgreSQL Multiple USING clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, using

I often find myself using (no pun intended) the *USING* clause in **PostgreSQL**, and was wondering how the choice would be made in case of multiple *USING* on the same key name.

Let me explain with a simple example :
Let table A, B and C having the *userid* column.
If I am doing :

```
SELECT A.c1, A.c2, ...
FROM A
JOIN B USING(userid)
JOIN C USING(userid) ;
```

How does Postrges manages the conflict emerging from the fact that both tables B and C have the column *userid* ? What is the output resulting from ?

```
A.userid = B.userid AND A.userid = C.userid
```

or

```
A.userid = B.userid AND B.userid = C.userid
```

I hope I have been clear enough, thank you in advance for your answer.

*PS : I am not doing multiple USING clause because I find that unreadable, but I was wondering how it worked.*

Comment: `JOIN C USING(userid)` uses the one and only userid from the previous join, neither A or B's.

Comment: Your question concerns the order of processing of the query. As indicated the explain plan will show you the process on your system with your data volume at present. However that sequence is not fixed. The optimizer chooses the order of operation based on available indexes, table size, current statistics, etc.  As those change the plan itself also (may) changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With inner joins, this query:

```
SELECT A.c1, A.c2, ...
FROM A JOIN
     B
     USING (userid) JOIN
     C
     USING (userid) ;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
SELECT A.c1, A.c2, ...
FROM A JOIN
     B
     ON B.userid = A.userid JOIN
     C
     ON C.userid = A.userid ;  -- or "C.userid = B.userid", it doesn't matter
```

Note that `NULL` values fail the comparison for an `INNER JOIN`, so they are not an issue because they are not in the result set.

For `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, the logic would be the same as above.  For a `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT A.c1, A.c2, ...
FROM A FULL JOIN
     B
     ON B.userid = A.userid FULL JOIN
     C
     ON C.userid = COALESCE(A.userid, B.userid) ;
```

Note that throughout the rest of the query `userid`, with no qualification, refers to the non-`NULL` value from whatever table.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `USING`, you will have only a single `userid` in the join result, so there will be no ambiguity.

All [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) has to say is

> Furthermore, the output of `JOIN USING` suppresses redundant columns:

but it also refers to column references. You can use `userid` without a table qualification and you won't get an "ambiguous column reference" error, because PostgreSQL knows that the column exists only once.

Comment: That's fine as long as those joins are Inner Join, but what if the joins are Outer Joins? At least the syntax allows it.

Comment: Then you get the non-null value.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense, I just checked the SQL Standard, the result it actually defined using COALESCE.

Answer (score 2):

You can explain the plan and check:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  userid INT
, nm VARCHAR(32)
);
CREATE TABLE b (
  userid INT
, adr VARCHAR(32)
);
CREATE TABLE c (
  userid INT
, car VARCHAR(32)
);

EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b USING(userid)
JOIN c USING(userid)
;
-- out                               QUERY PLAN                               
-- out -----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- out  Merge Join  (cost=152.17..334.01 rows=8946 width=250)
-- out    Merge Cond: (a.userid = c.userid)
-- out    ->  Merge Join  (cost=101.45..142.80 rows=2520 width=172)
-- out          Merge Cond: (a.userid = b.userid)
-- out          ->  Sort  (cost=50.72..52.50 rows=710 width=86)
-- out                Sort Key: a.userid
-- out                ->  Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..17.10 rows=710 width=86)
-- out          ->  Sort  (cost=50.72..52.50 rows=710 width=86)
-- out                Sort Key: b.userid
-- out                ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..17.10 rows=710 width=86)
-- out    ->  Sort  (cost=50.72..52.50 rows=710 width=86)
-- out          Sort Key: c.userid
-- out          ->  Seq Scan on c  (cost=0.00..17.10 rows=710 width=86)

-- and with a full outer join:

EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM a
FULL JOIN b USING(userid)
FULL JOIN c USING(userid)
;
-- out                                  QUERY PLAN                                  
-- out -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- out  Merge Full Join  (cost=326.16..463.90 rows=8946 width=250)
-- out    Merge Cond: (c.userid = (COALESCE(a.userid, b.userid)))
-- out    ->  Sort  (cost=50.72..52.50 rows=710 width=86)
-- out          Sort Key: c.userid
-- out          ->  Seq Scan on c  (cost=0.00..17.10 rows=710 width=86)
-- out    ->  Sort  (cost=275.43..281.73 rows=2520 width=172)
-- out          Sort Key: (COALESCE(a.userid, b.userid))
-- out          ->  Hash Full Join  (cost=25.98..133.06 rows=2520 width=172)
-- out                Hash Cond: (a.userid = b.userid)
-- out                ->  Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..17.10 rows=710 width=86)
-- out                ->  Hash  (cost=17.10..17.10 rows=710 width=86)
-- out                      ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..17.10 rows=710 width=86)
```